I need help figuring out what is wrong with this chrome extension that is supposed to intercept GET requests
Here's my manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "GET Request Interceptor",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab"
    ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon.svg",
        "48": "icons/icon.svg",
        "128": "icons/icon.svg"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon.svg"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]  
}

Here's my background.js:
let validDomains = [];
let interceptRegex = null;

// Load valid domains and intercept regex at startup
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('valid-domains.txt'))
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    validDomains = text.split('\n').map(domain => domain.trim()).filter(domain => domain);
    console.log('Valid domains loaded:', validDomains);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Failed to load valid domains:', error));

// Load the regex for path matching from intercept-file.txt
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('intercept-file.txt'))
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((regexText) => {
    try {
      // Create a regular expression object from the file content
      interceptRegex = new RegExp(regexText.trim());
      console.log('Intercept regex loaded:', interceptRegex);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Invalid regex in intercept-file.txt:', error);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Failed to load intercept regex:', error));

// Helper function to extract the root domain from a hostname
function getRootDomain(hostname) {
  const parts = hostname.split('.').reverse();
  if (parts.length >= 2) {
    return `${parts[1]}.${parts[0]}`;
  }
  return hostname; // Fallback for localhost or unusual domains
}

// Transform function to modify the original content
function transformContent(originalContent) {
  return originalContent; // Just return original content for now
}

// Initialize message listeners
function setupMessageListeners() {
  const messageListener = (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.type === 'intercept-fetch' || message.type === 'intercept-xmlhttp') {
      const { url, method } = message;

      // Fetch the original content
      fetch(url, { method: method || 'GET' })
        .then((response) => response.text().then((body) => ({ response, body })))
        .then(({ response, body }) => {
          const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
          const domain = getRootDomain(parsedUrl.hostname);
          const path = parsedUrl.pathname;

          console.log("Intercepted GET request: ", domain, path);

          // Check if the domain is valid
          if (validDomains.includes(domain) && interceptRegex.test(path)) {
            // Transform content if regex matches
            const transformedContent = transformContent(body);

            sendResponse({
              status: 200,
              statusText: response.statusText,
              headers: Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries()),
              body: transformedContent
            });
          } else {
            // Return original content if no match
            sendResponse({
              status: response.status,
              statusText: response.statusText,
              headers: Object.fromEntries(response.headers.entries()),
              body
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error fetching original content:', error);
          sendResponse({ status: 404, statusText: 'Cannot find content', body: '' });
        });

      return true; // Keep the message channel open for async response
    }
  };

  // Register the message listener
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messageListener);
}

// Initialize listeners when the worker starts
setupMessageListeners();

And here's my content.js:
console.log("Content script running");

// Intercept fetch API
const originalFetch = window.fetch;
window.fetch = async (...args) => {
    const [resource, config] = args;

    // Send the request details to the service worker
    const message = {
        type: 'intercept-fetch',
        url: resource,
        method: config?.method || 'GET',
        headers: config?.headers,
        body: config?.body
    };

    // Send message to service worker and wait for response
    const response = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, resolve);
    });

    if (response && response.status) {
        // Construct a Response object with the data from the service worker
        return new Response(response.body, {
            status: response.status,
            statusText: response.statusText,
            headers: new Headers(response.headers)
        });
    }

    // Fallback to original fetch if no valid response received
    return originalFetch(...args);
};

// Intercept XMLHttpRequest
const originalXHROpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async = true, user, password) {
    this._intercepted = { method, url };
    return originalXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
};

const originalXHRSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (body) {
    if (this._intercepted) {
        const { method, url } = this._intercepted;

        // Send the request details to the service worker
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            {
                type: 'intercept-xmlhttp',
                url,
                method,
                body
            },
            (response) => {
                if (response && response.status) {
                    // Replace the XHR response
                    Object.defineProperty(this, 'responseText', {
                        get: () => response.body,
                    });

                    this.status = response.status;
                    this.statusText = response.statusText;

                    // Trigger readystatechange event
                    this.readyState = 4;
                    this.onreadystatechange && this.onreadystatechange();
                    this.onload && this.onload();
                } else {
                    // Fallback to original XHR send if no valid response received
                    originalXHRSend.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        // No interception, proceed with original send
        originalXHRSend.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};

I'm not even seeing the console.log at the beginning of content.js from the developers tools, either on the service worker's console or the page's console, although the developer's console clearly shows me that my content.js is listed among the sources.   The only logs that I do see are on the extension's console that shows when some of its starting resource have been loaded.
I've been adding console log message throughout to try and diagnose the problem, but have not had any luck figuring out what I'm doing wrong.   I was hoping to see some evidence that my custom interception code was getting called, but I haven't seen any.   I've looked at similar questions from stackoverflow, but have not been able to generalize from the answers what I could be doing wrong in my case.   My guess is that it's probably something really simple, probably a line or two, that I'm forgetting that is causing this to not work properly.
Oh, and before anyone asks, the resources that my program is reading are all there, and have been confirmed to be valid.
My question is different from Access variables and functions defined in page context from an extension in that I'm not tring to access any variables defined in a page context from the extension.  My problem is that the service worker isn't seeing the messages that I try to post from there in the first place.   If these questions are somehow related, the way that they are is elusive to me.

You need to run the content script in the MAIN world and then use externally_connectable messaging or use two content scripts (the interceptor in the MAIN world will send CustomEvent message, the normal content script will receive it and relay it via chrome.runtime.sendMessage).

Thanks, but that doesn't explain why nothing in content.js seems to ever be running in the first place.   Even the console log message at the beginning isn't showing up anywhere.

Content scripts run only when the tab is [re]loaded. See how to re-inject files from content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome.
